# Azure DevOps - Prohibit the most recent pusher from approving their own changes - Reviewer not able to accept his own changes

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, pull-request, branching-and-merging

We are using Azure DevOps. 'Minimum number of reviewers' is set to 1, 'Allow requestors to approve their own changes' is enabled in branch specific policy and 'Prohibit the most recent pusher from approving their own changes' is checked in 'Cross-Repository policies for master'.

The issue we face is that, if a developer who is also a reviewer create a pull request, he cannot approve his own pull request and needs to wait for a review. Is it possible to give permission for reviewers to accept their own changes?

Answer (score 1):

Even if I am against approving your own PR, you can enable it by

`Branch Policies -->  Allow requestors to approve their own changes`

Comment: I missed to add that in the question. 'Allow requestors to approve their own changes' is already enabled in branch specific policy. But still, when the reviewer is creating a pull request, it waits for an approval and reviewer cannot approve it.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in DevOps when "When new changes are pushed: **Require at least one approval on the last iteration**" is checked.  If you change that setting to "When new changes are pushed: **Reset all approval votes ...**" then it will allow them to approve their own request."